# Intellij IDEA - Maven not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I cannot see the list of maven archetypes ("Loading archetype list...") or import an existing maven project in Intellij IDEA 2016.3.4. I tried several things:

- giving more memory to maven JVM
- clearing "VM options for importer" setting
- switching between bundled and external maven directories
- switching between JDK's used by maven
- invalidating IDEA cache
- removing .m2 directory
- adding "127.0.0.0 localhost" line in hosts

and none of it worked. Here is a fragment of IDEA log file:

```
    ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Cannot reconnect. 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot reconnect.
        at                 org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.        java:82)
        at         org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper.getArchetypes(MavenIndexerWr        apper.java:175)
        at         org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager.getArchetypes(MavenIndicesM        anager.java:310)
        at         org.jetbrains.idea.maven.wizards.MavenArchetypesStep.lambda$updateArchetypesList        $2(MavenArchetypesStep.java:237)
        at         com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java        :309)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Cannot start maven service; nested exception is: 
        com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: 
        at         org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:173)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:78)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$4.create(MavenServerManager.java:527)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager$4.create(MavenServerManager.java:523)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.getOrCreateWrappee(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:41)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:178)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenIndexerWrapper$7.execute(MavenIndexerWrapper.java:175)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteObjectWrapper.perform(RemoteObjectWrapper.java:76)
... 9 more
    Caused by: com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: 
        at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteProcessSupport.acquire(RemoteProcessSupport.java:159)
        at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.MavenServerManager.create(MavenServerManager.java:170)
        ... 17 more
    2017-02-05 14:27:24,061 [ 123449]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4  Build #IU-163.12024.16 
    2017-02-05 14:27:24,061 [ 123449]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - JDK: 1.8.0_121 
    2017-02-05 14:27:24,061 [ 123449]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
    2017-02-05 14:27:24,061 [ 123449]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
    2017-02-05 14:27:24,061 [ 123449]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - OS: Windows 10 
    2017-02-05 14:27:24,061 [ 123449]  ERROR - plication.impl.ApplicationImpl - Last Action: NewProject 
    2017-02-05 14:27:30,668 [ 130056]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
    Exit code 1
```

Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Comment: Does gradle work?

Comment: Have you simply tried to run Maven on command line?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda yes

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, it works fine

Comment: Maybe hanging maven server process using port number? Anything in task manager? Update Intellij?

Answer (score 1):

[Nvidia Geforce 378.57 Hot Fix Drivers](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/geforce-378-57-hotfix-driver-download.html):

- Fixed crash in Minecraft and some other Java-based titles

There were many reports of IntelliJ IDEA, Maven and user applications crashing with Nvidia driver 378.49. Downgrading to the previous version or installing the hotfix from the link above should help if your problem was also caused by this driver update.

In case the above doesn't apply to your system, [please contact JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).